# Chiral Condensate and Parity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, parity

Chiral condensation is known to be characterized by the nontrivial expectation value of
$$\langle \chi_{ai}^{\alpha} \xi_{\alpha  j}^a\rangle= U_{ij}$$
where $\chi$ is the left handed Weyl fermion and $\xi$ is the right handed Weyl. $\alpha=1,...,N$ is the color index, $a=1,2$ is the spinor index, and $i,j=1,...,N_f$ is the flavor index. I used the notation from Mark Srednicki: https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf.

However, under parity $P$, using 
$$P^{-1} \chi_{a}P= i (\xi^{\dagger})^{\dot a}$$
$$P^{-1} \xi_{a}P= i (\chi^{\dagger})^{\dot a}$$
it is straight forward to check that the parity $P$ maps $U$ to $U^\dagger$. So the condensate seems to spontaneously break the parity symmetry unless $U$ is Hermitian.

> So my question is shall we treat the $U$ as the chiral condensate? or shall we just treat the Hermitian part of $U$, i.e., $U+ U^\dagger$ as the chiral condensate?

Comment: tldr; [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0210398.pdf) is a better reference with vastly better notation. The chiral condensate is basically a nonvanihing v.e.v. of the scalar singlet, so L-R symmetric and parity preserving: $\langle \bar \psi \psi\rangle\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first right down the condensate in its simpler version (or perhaps more common presentation) 
$$\langle \bar{q}q\rangle = \langle \bar{u}u + \bar{d}d + \bar{s}s\rangle$$
As you can see it is a hermitian operator from the start, which makes sense because it is an expectation value we could observe.

The standard theory uses this expectation value as an order parameter for the spontaneous breaking of chiral symmetry [See. [1,2]]. You can see this by performing a chiral transformation to the quarks involved, i.e.
$$\psi \rightarrow e^{i\alpha\gamma_5 T_a}\psi \qquad \text{and}\qquad \bar{\psi}\rightarrow \bar{\psi}e^{i\alpha\gamma_5 T_a}$$
or alternatively 
$$\psi_L \rightarrow e^{i\alpha T_a}\psi_L\qquad \text{and}\qquad \psi_R\rightarrow e^{-i\alpha T_a}\psi_R.$$

I believe Srednicki is just writing the same thing in a matrix version such that one can compare generators directly, he then motivates the pion effective Lagrangian where later adds a general mass (Srednicki Eq. 83.14). One does need the hermitian conjugate, so that we associate a real parameter to it (namely masses).

---

[1] S. Scherer, A Primer for Chiral Perturbation Theory, (2011), Springer.

[2] J. Donoghue, Dynamics of the Standard Model, (2014), Cambridge University Press.

Comment: thanks! I am confused with your last comment: shouldn't the chiral condensate parameterize the whole SU(3) manifold? This is why we need to use the  chiral Lagrangian with SU(3) target space to describe the low energy theory. Your last comment seems to suggest that the chiral condensate only parameterizes the Hermitian sub-manifold of the SU(3) manifold.

Comment: All I am saying is it is a symmetry breaking parameter. On the one side you can "choose" the way you break the symmetry that is given implicitly by taking the condensate to be proportional to the identity. In this case it coincides with an observable (can be also understood as related to the pion decay constant) so you can additionally say it must be real. It does not need to parameterize the whole manifold after all physical considerations are made. Namely that you want some matching of high and low energy theories.